# Oracle Error Logging ORA-01858 in err$ table

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to capture an ORA-01858 error I'm receiving on a batch job that uses a merge statement.  It throws an exception but trying to capture this in the error log table I created using DBMS_ERRLOG.create_error_log('mytable').  So my pseudo-code is as follows:

```
    merge into table1
    using
    (select columns from table2 --staging table
    )
    when matched then update table1 with values from table2
    when not matched then
      insert values from table2 to table1
      log errors into err$_myerroortable ('log message')

EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        v_message_type := 'E';
        v_message_text := 'Merge pur pol shop data process failed'
                          || ' with error '
                          || sqlerrm;
        conadm.refresh_conshop_to_shop.insert_appl_log(v_job_name,
                                                       v_package_name,
                                                       v_procedure_name,
                                                       v_message_text,
                                                       v_message_type);
```

The above code works fine on logging any unique constraint violations with the insert. However, another error that I just get an exception on is an ORA-01858: non-numeric character error. I want to log this error in the error log table I created so we can go back after batch job and see which rows job failed on without erroring out of the job for other records.  Using Oracle 12c. I do not wish to resolve the numeric error at this time, but just to log it during each batch run. Thanks in advance for any help with this.

This is my pseudo-code I'm currently using.

```
merge into table1
using
(select columns from table2 --staging table
)
when matched then update table1 with values from table2
when not matched then
insert values from table2 to table1
log errors into err$_myerroortable ('log message')

    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            v_message_type := 'E';
            v_message_text := 'Merge pur pol shop data process failed'
                              || ' with error '
                              || sqlerrm;
            conadm.refresh_conshop_to_shop.insert_appl_log(v_job_name,
                                                          v_package_name,
                                                          v_procedure_name,
                                                          v_message_text,
                                                          v_message_type);
```

Comment: I'm not quite clear what the issue is here. Does your DML exceptions (`log errors into` clause) capture unique constraint exceptions but not non-numeric character exceptions?

Comment: By the way, it's best if your logging procedure captures exception and session details itself (calling procedure, dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace etc) rather than having each procedure try to do it every time and inevitably lose details and get inconsistent results.

Comment: As of [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/admin/managing-tables.html#GUID-B8C0D6EE-6D5E-4415-90F5-81B310201440). *Oracle Database logs the following errors during DML operations: •Column values that are too large •Constraint violations (NOT NULL, unique, referential, and check constraints) •Errors raised during trigger execution •Errors resulting from type conversion between a column in a subquery and the corresponding column of the table •Partition mapping errors •Certain MERGE operation errors (ORA-30926)*

Comment: Yes, correct.  I'm just trying to capture the error in the err$ log table and currently it just throws exception but need to capture this information in log table for non-numeric character exceptions.

Comment: Also, I have another log that captures stored proc name and error but I'm trying to also capture which row is having problem within the batch and put this in my log table.